# How to modify file before sending (Node js)

Tags: node.js, express, fileserver

I have a nodejs application which sends requested files from path, I want to modify and update the "src" & "href" tags before sending them, I'm using res.sendFile("path to file") but I want to modify this file before sending, Is there any way by which I can do that

```
Router.get("/report/", (req, res) => {
  const path = req.query.drive + req.query.file;

  const options = {
    project: req.query.project,
    type: "static_analysis_report1"
  };

  fs.createReadStream(path)
    .pipe(new ModifyFile(options))
    .pipe(res);
});
```

ModifyFile class

```
class ModifyFile extends Transform {
  project_name = "";
  type = "";

  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
    this.project_name = options.project_name;
    this.type = options.type;
  }

  _transform(chunk, encoding, cb) {
    const project_name = this.project_name;
    const type = this.type;

    var htmlCode = chunk.toString();
    console.log(htmlCode);
    cb();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can create Trasform stream for it, Code will be like `fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(new MyTransform()).pipe(res);`

Comment: Can you please tell me what would be the response?? (i.e res) and am I to include this in my Router.get() ??

Comment: `const { Transform } = require('stream');
const  { createReadStream } = require('fs');

const myTransform = new Transform({
  transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
     this.push(chunk); // <--- modify it
     callback();
  }
});



app.get('/', function(req, res) {
      createReadStream('some file').pipe(myTransform).pipe(res);
});`

Comment: Thanks a lot but just one more question, How will I send the modified file back??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example based on stream

```
const { Transform } = require('stream');
const  { createReadStream } = require('fs');
const {join} = require('path');

const myTransform = new Transform({
  transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
     this.push(chunk); // <--- modify it
     callback();
  }
});

app.get('/:file', function(req, res) {
      createReadStream(join(__dirname, req.params.file)).pipe(myTransform).pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: I want a value from req.query.project how can I access that inside myTransform??

Comment: Just create my Transformer as class, not as instance and create new instance on each request. In this case you can pass any parameters via constructor. https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_new_stream_transform_options

Comment: Sorry to bother you but how will I end the request??

Comment: pipe close response automatically on end of file

Comment: I'm not getting the file as response though

Comment: Strange, check method flush in our Transform stream

Comment: This works once and then fails with `write after end`

Answer (score 3):

String example

```
  import Express from 'express';
  import path from 'path';
  import { readFile } from 'fs';
  import util from 'util';
  
  const readFileAsync = util.promisify(readFile);
  const app = new Express();
  
  app.get('/file/url', async (req, res) => {
    let index = await readFileAsync(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'), 'utf8');
   
    index = index.replace('SOMETHING', 'SOMETHING ELSE'); //MODIFY THE FILE AS A STRING HERE
    return res.send(index);
  });
  
  export default app;
```

Answer (score -3):

Use Callbacks or Promises to update the data before.